# Accessing HTML Element after Adding with innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, addeventlistener

I am adding the data received as a result of a request to my page as follows.

```
showMovieInfo(movies) {
    this.tableDiv.innerHTML = "";

    movies.forEach(movie => {
        this.tableDiv.innerHTML += 
        `
        <table class="table align-middle mb-0 bg-white">
        <thead class="bg-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Movie Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <img src="${movie.image}"
                            alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 120px" class="rounded-circle" />
                        <div class="ms-3">
                            <p class="fw-bold mb-1">${movie.title}</p>
                            <p class="text-muted mb-0">${movie.description}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button  type="button" id="showonmap" class="btn btn-link btn-sm btn-rounded">
                        Show on map
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>`

    });
}
```

then i want to add addEventListener to buttons with id="showonmap".But I am getting an error  and when I click the buttons, any function does not work.

Comment: What error are you getting? And you should change it to a class of 'showonmap' as it's incorrect and invalid to have duplicate IDs in your page.

Comment: You would need to register a `delegated event handler` to the parent element ( or other higher level element ) and use  the `event` to identify the element that actually invoked the `click` event ( ie: buttons )

Comment: im getting -Uncaught ReferenceError: showButton is not defined
    at eventListeners-

Comment: Also very worth noting is that ID attributes **must* be unique so adding this string of HTML with `id="showonmap"` would violate that uniqueness principle. You have not shown where/how you are trying to bind event handlers which might be useful to others

Comment: I want to capture whichever button was clicked among the added movies. but now I can't reach the added button.

Comment: Yes, `"can't reach the added button"` because the eventlisteners were added to the DOM before this code/html. Bind a delegated listener to the parent element `this.tableDiv` etc

Answer (score 0):

To support the comment made above regarding the `delegated event listener` I quickly rattled up this simple demo that slightly rewrites your original class method as a standalone function so that you can see the effect in action. As the event handler is assigned to a parent element within the DOM which **does** exist when the page is loaded you can use the `event` to identify which button ( or other element ) was clicked and from there do whatever operations are required.

```js
const movies = [{
    image: 'http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQsJW_I8KPZiq4mXcpRCd8uKBsUMR4Gz691k6gwEiLqVOoTl8pf',
    title: 'The Life of Brian',
    description: 'this is a great movie'
  },
  {
    image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOTI4MDdjMmUtOTZhOS00MTYwLWEyZTUtYTdhMTQxNGM1YTUxXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMzg1ODEwNQ@@._V1_UX140_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg',
    title: 'The Wasp Woman',
    description: 'this is a terrible movie'
  }
];



// slightly re-written as no longer part of a class/object
showMovieInfo = (movies) => {
  // exlicitly define this.tableDiv here rather than in constructor earlier ( & not shown )
  this.tableDiv = document.getElementById('movies');
  this.tableDiv.innerHTML = "";

  movies.forEach(movie => {
    this.tableDiv.innerHTML +=
      `
        <table class="table align-middle mb-0 bg-white">
            <thead class="bg-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>Movie Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <img src="${movie.image}"
                                alt="" style="width: 120px; height: 120px" class="rounded-circle" />
                            <div class="ms-3">
                                <p class="fw-bold mb-1">${movie.title}</p>
                                <p class="text-muted mb-0">${movie.description}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td><!-- modified id to data-id and added data-title for demo -->
                        <button  type="button" data-id="showonmap" data-title="${movie.title}" class="btn btn-link btn-sm btn-rounded">
                            Show on map
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`;
  });



  this.tableDiv.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target != e.currentTarget && e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON' && e.target.hasAttribute('data-id')) {
      alert(e.target.dataset.title);
      // ... here you would do other operations to actually "view on map"
      // ... etc
    }
  })
}

showMovieInfo(movies);
```

```html
<div id='movies'></div>
```